# WCF EndPoints not working with IIS hosting

Tags: wcf, iis, endpoint

I have following settings

```
<services>
    <service name="HelloWCFServiceClass.clsHelloWCFServiceClass" >
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:6789/IISHosting/HelloWorldISSHostedService.svc"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"  contract="HelloWCFServiceContract.IHelloWCFServiceContract" />
      <endpoint address="/test" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                         contract="HelloWCFServiceContract.IHelloWCFServiceContract"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

I can open

```
http://{ServerName}:6789/HelloWorldISSHostedService.svc
```

But I'm getting an error

> The webpage cannot be found

while trying to access through end point like this

```
http://{ServerName}:6789/HelloWorldISSHostedService.svc/test
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `BasicHttpBinding` - that's a **SOAP** binding, you cannot just use your browser to browse to that endpoint.

You'll need to use something like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) to test your SOAP services.

If you want a service that's testable in your browser (by just navigating to an URL), you need to use the `webHttpBinding` instead (**REST** service)

Comment: I changed BasicHttpBinding to wsHttpBinding but I am not able to open http://{ServerName}:6789/HelloWorldISSHostedService.svc/test. Getting "HTTP 400 Bad Request" I just want to add multiple endpoints to my WCF application

Comment: @user2589824: if you're hosting in IIS, then your base address in the config file is useless - the *real* service address is determined by the IIS host name, the virtual directory where your `*.svc` file lives, and the name of the `*.svc` file itself.

Comment: @user2589824: **plus:** even if your base address in the config *would* work - your URL you're navigating to is not a match to what you have configured: your config file has `.../IISHosting/.....` while the URL you're using is missing that `IISHosting` part....

Comment: yes I m using IIS hosting. in that case what would be the url?

Comment: @user2589824: I just explained that! It's `http://YourServerName/YourVirtualDirectory/HelloWorldIISHostedService.svc` ....

Comment: then in this case if I have two end point with address ="/test" and address ="/test2" then how can I use both end point.

Comment: @user2589824: hmm.... is your `HelloWorldISSHostedService.svc` file really at the **root** of your IIS structure? Can you check in IIS Manager? Typically, it would be something like `http://(servername)/VirtualDirectoryName/HelloWorldISSHostedService.svc` - usually you store this inside a **virtual directory** (or an application) inside IIS ... also: typically, IIS uses **port 80** (and not something like `6789`) as its HTTP port...

Answer (score 0):

If your service is part of an MVC project, you need to configure your routing table

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs